# CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes depreicated iOS9

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios9

[image]

I am using parse framework for my iOS9 app. However this error comes out and I'm not sure how to change it to the recommended code. I've tried entering what they suggested and it doesn't seems to be right

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. Deprecated means, might be broken in the future but is still working

Comment: @vadian Do you have any idea how to change to the recommended code in swift?

Comment: ⌘-click on the symbol. You will see the complete warning message: *Use [NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:] instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent (since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid).* The `NSCharacterSet` instance to be passed depends on which part of the URL you want to encode. Please read the documentation of `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`